# Is it possible to include non-symfony apps into symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Take [PHP Invoiceplane](https://github.com/InvoicePlane/InvoicePlane) for example. Rather than setting up a subdomain for this "standalone" application, it would be nice to include it into our main symfony app.

I'm fairly new to symfony, so I have no idea if this is possible and if it would be easy or very hard.

Is it possible? How should I tackle it, if so?

Comment: You can add it via composer https://github.com/InvoicePlane/InvoicePlane/blob/master/composer.json, but you will need additional tweaking to make it work together

Comment: I've taken a similar approach before with a CodeIgniter app and a Wordpress site and I would not recommend it. It's better to try to keep them separate and have them communicate via a REST API if possible.